# TestNg emailable-report is not updating?

Tags: selenium, testng

When I am running the `tesng.xml` file by running it by right clicking on it ,the `emailable-report.html` file is showing as per the latest test result ,but While running it from terminal by "`mvn test`" test results are coming as per expected but `emailable-report.html` file is updated as per the current result .[image: maven results]
[image: emailable-report]

Comment: I think your question and description causing conflict. What you want is not clear

Comment: @Sidhartha `test results are coming as per expected` so where is the problem? Thanks

Comment: @Dev While running with "mvn test" ,emailable-report is not getting updated with current test results .

Comment: @Sidhartha Can you consider showing us your work please? Thanks

Comment: @Dev I have attached the screenshot please check.Actually while running the selenium code through maven the testng emailable file is not getting updated as per the result .

Comment: @Sidhartha I think once maven is done with the Test, you need to refresh your Project `DataVisualization` once to get the fresh reports

Comment: But wait, why don't you copy the `emailable-report` to `target` where maven works at its best? Thanks

Comment: emailable-report is within the "test-output" folder ,which is the default folder structure .

Comment: Tell me first, did you refresh your Project `DataVisualization` once to get the fresh reports? Are you seeing them with fresh data & formatting? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145111/discussion-between-sidhartha-and-dev).

Comment: If you're still having problems, you might want to try a mvn clean

Comment: @Sidhartha : delete the report and try again

Comment: Use IExecutionListener and call sendmail method from onExecutionFinish() method.It will definetely send latest emailable report.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because your report is probably generated in target folder when you run it with maven and in test-output when running it via testng.xml directly. So you are probably expecting it to be in different place and you are opening wrong report, while your latest report is in target folder.

Comment: In the target  folder within surefire-reports ?

Comment: Yes, it should be there

Comment: Thank you .I got it int location "target/surefire-reports/testng-native-results/emailable-report.html"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but the folder was ok. The problem is that the emailable-report.html generation occurs after all the execution, including the annotations @After.... What I did is using Reporter.getCurrentTestResult(); in @AfterTest before performing the email send action to have the file updated at the right time.